# Android EditextField and bottom button changing the keyboard focus

Tags: android, android-activity, android-keypad, window-soft-input-mode

I have an activity with 5 EditText views and a bottom button. I specified

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

here everything work fine only once, that is the EditText field is staying just above the bottom button, it lost it's focus if it has the cursor on it or any text. I tried changing the

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

but here it brings up the bottom button above the keyboard. What should I change for making it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Using `adjustResize` resizes the layout so the button bar appears above the EditTexts. You can combine the adjustment specifications. Try if you can get the desired result.

e.g.:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >
```

for further information: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)